# How to display data in its respective column and filter by name keeping the name and age consistent in each row in Angular?

Tags: angular

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
   if(!items) return [];
   if(!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
   return items.filter( it => {
  return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
  });
 }
}
```

> Here I get an error such that 'ERROR TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function'

**app.component.ts**

```
   @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
  })

  export class AppComponent  {
     name = 'Angular';

  characters  = [
     {name:'Finn the shark',age:'10'},
     {name:'Jake the dog',age:'4'},
     {name:'Princess Bubble gum',age:'1'}
    ];
  }
```

> I want to work with an array like this, not : characters=['Finn the shark','Jake the dog','Princess Bubble gum'];

**HTML**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here">
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Characters</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>


  <tr *ngFor="let c of characters | filter : searchText   let i = index">
   <th>{{characters[i].name}}</th>
   <th>{{characters[i].age}}</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

> Table populates as expected, however, the filter does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the items are null or empty, add a check

```
if(items && items.length > 0){
 return items.filter( it => {
  return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
});
}
```

Comment: where did you get count from? Is this incremented? Thanks

Comment: sorry that should be .length

Comment: when I type in the input box, everything dissapears